# Find the distance to the centre of the grid

Tags: geometry

I am trying to find a length from the centre of a grid to points in a circular pattern around that centre point and the procedure escapes me. Going up/down/left/right is easy enough, but how do I calculate the angles and where to place points?

Here is an example to help visualize what I am asking:

[image]

Comment: The picture really doesn't help very much. Are you trying to find all the points less than, say, 10 units from the center?

Comment: Are you familiar with [polar coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system)?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes, I am trying to find all the coordinates within a set distance from the center.

Comment: @ja72 I am not, but I will definitely read up on that. Thanks!

Comment: OK, Sean, but I take it you are happy with the answer ja72 has posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If two points are $X$ grids apart horizontally and $Y$ grids apart vertically then use the following

$$ {\rm distance} = \sqrt{X^2+Y^2} \\
   {\rm angle} = {\rm atan2}(Y,X)
$$

<sup>NOTE:</sup> The [`Atan2`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2) function is common on computer languages.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for, thanks!